# how do place UI in code at bottom screen?

Tags: c#, gui, unity-ui

I am struggling to figure out how I can add a UI prefab on screen in code so that it appears "anchored" at the bottom center of the screen. I realize this might be a common question. I apologize. Googling has not given me an answer yet. Most answers do not show me how to do it in code.  Some referenced anchors but I do not see anchor fields or properties on my types.   It might be I do not understand the terminology correctly to find the answer.

It's likely the problem is this line **control.transform.position = Vector3.zero** but I do not know how to fix it.

[image]

This is how I make the prefab appear on screen. It is currently centered on screen.

```
public class PopupHandler : IPopupHandler
{
   
    public Canvas Canvas { get; set; }

    public void ShowPopup(GameObject popup)
    {
        if (null == popup)
            return;
        
        var control = Canvas.Instantiate<GameObject>(popup);
        control.SetActive(true);

        control.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        control.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        control.transform.SetParent(Canvas.transform, true);
    }
}
```

Here's the prefab constructions:
[image]

Comment: Looks like 0 is the center of the screen. Try giving it some other vector, and look where it moves.

Comment: You want to be using the RectTransform component if you are dealing with objects on a canvas rather than the usual Transform.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html

Comment: If you'd like to answer your own question and mark it as accepted just so the Community bot doesn't keep bumping the question, otherwise I will write an answer in an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I said in the comments you'd want to access the UI's RectTransform component rather than it's Transform component.

Then you can set the anchors of the component to the center-bottom, after that you can calculate where it should be positioned.

```
public class PopupHandler : IPopupHandler
{

    public Canvas Canvas { get; set; }

    public void ShowPopup(GameObject popup)
    {
        if (null == popup)
            return;

        var control = Canvas.Instantiate<GameObject>(popup);
        control.SetActive(true);


        RectTransform RectTransform = control.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
         //set the anchors to the center - bottom of the bar
        RectTransform.anchorMin.Set(0.5f, 0);
        RectTransform.anchorMax.Set(0.5f, 0);


        control.transform.SetParent(Canvas.transform);

        //width = Screen width halfed minus rect width half
        //height = 0 (for bottom) + half of rect height
        RectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(Screen.width / 2 - RectTransform.rect.width / 2, 0 + RectTransform.rect.height / 2, 0);
        control.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    }
}
```

I created a test scene and it seems to work fine for me, but in my scene the canvas it is parented to takes up all available screen space so I can use Screen.width and Screen.height, you may need to use the Canvas width and height if yours doesn't.

Comment: I can confirm that works.  Thank you.  I completely forgot that I get RetTransform via the "GetComponent" method.  I kept looking for it as a property of "control"

Comment: I had to change it slightly though.   I first had to get the canvas from the control.  var controlCanvas = control.GetComponentInChildren<Canvas> and get the RecTransform from the canvas.